# Hacking Razor partial views into a WebForms project in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, webforms

So, I'm supporting a project made with WebForms,
I've upgraded it to MVC5 and want to use Razor views for new features I'm adding. Why I want to do this is because I've no time/will to rewrite all the stuff I got for pure Razor view.

There used to be a hack to achieve this sort of stuff by extending the controller and rendering the razor view **inside the aspx** view as a **partial**. [described here](http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2011/01/07/Using-Razor-Pages-with-WebForms-Master-Pages.aspx)

But this was in MVC3, applied to my project it throws a StackOverflowException when trying to render the page.

Any ideas of achieving it in MVC5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmpf, googling this topic looked so obscure...
Actually, the solution is really straightforward.

two files:

```
SomeView.aspx
SomeView_Razor.cshtml
```

Aspx one incorporates the site.master and all the things I need.
And this little fella :

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("SomeView_Razor"); %>
```

Voila!